# How can I update the mongoDB record with doing action at frontend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

So what I want to achieve is: 1.Press on the button 2.It toggles its state(I made a toggle function). 3.It sends the current state to database. 4. Record with button's state changes 5. I close the app, run it again and it gets the data with the current state of button.

[image]

So now comes a question: How can I do that? I didn't really find anything useful to make that specific connection database-frontend.

// There is a lot of code which I dont want to spam with so make it simple: I already GET data from database and the BNS-H11 you can see its the result of it.
 I call it with componentDidMount().
I passed props to the components.

```
//ISLbutton.js   < button component
const [name, setName] = useState(props.islName),
const [islIsOn, setIslIsOn] = useState(props.islIsOn)

 // functions for auth check and toggle...
```

Comment: I suppose it is somewhat related to storing of user preferences/profile, why not have a user preference end point in your backend to handle all the stuff of updating the user profile in mongodb.

Comment: No, its not user preference.. Lets say its some kind of panel that people will look at get some information but only people with permission will be able to change things on it. I actually have an endpoint '/api/bns' which holds all of the data( name of button, state of button, name of 2nd button,...., etc)

Comment: ok, so won't it be good to send user permissions list to the client when the user login to the app ?

Comment: Dont worry about it, its not a problem, i used redux for it and it actually works good. I have a problem with sending the data to database though. I want to make it 'global' and I kinda did ( in halfway) because it gets all data saved in database( data of buttons, textfields) but now I want to update that data